# Using Bi-Linear interpolation to scale an image up

Tags: matlab, loops, image-processing

The goal is to scale a 32x32 image into an 512x512 image using bi linear interpolation on MATLAB.

This basically means a mapping of every pixel in a 32x32 image to every sixteenth pixel on a 512x512 (because 512/32 = 16) image and the intensity of every pixel in between first and sixteen pixel is a linearly spaced rise of intensity values from that first pixel to the sixteen.

I wasn't able to get the accurate structure of the 'for' loop. I can iterate over every element, but in addition to that I would have to iterate horizontally through every row. Any idea how I would implement something like this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `imresize`? If you have code that isn't working, you should post it and point out specific problems you're having with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) should do what you want:

```
img32 = rand(32); % your image
[Xq, Yq] = ndgrid(linspace(1, 32, 512)); % query coordinate into 1:32
img512 = interp2(img32, Xq, Yq);
```